# Qual a forma mais eficiente de obter uma propriedade de uma Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Estou usando o `EF6` e gostaria de saber qual a forma de obter a melhor performance ao resgatar uma propriedade única de uma `Entity`.

Supondo o seguinte caso:

> *Vamos dizer que eu preciso buscar todos os nomes de uma tabela de usuários de 5000 linhas.*

***Classe User.cs***

```
public int ID {get; set;}

public string Name {get; set;}

um monte de coisa a mais...
```

Então montei essa função:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames()
{
   var list = new List<string>();
   var users = _context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.Name);
   foreach(var user in users)
   {
     list.Add(user.Name);
   }
   return list;
}
```

**E funcionou.**

Mas a pergunta fica: esta é a melhor forma? Por que estou pegando todos os usuários (objetos grandes) para depois só pegar uma única propriedade.

Se não for a melhor forma... qual é?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu trabalho com o NHibernate, mas acredito que você possa fazer algo nesse estilo.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames() => _context.Users.Select(u => u.Name).OrderBy(u => u);
```